# PCL library ICP algorithm return wrong transformation matrix

Tags: point-cloud-library

I just started to use PCL library to deal with the classic ICP problem, and to begin with, I tested it out the ICP function by calculating the transformation between two pair of 3D points, with each being `n = 4`. Yet, weirdly enough, despite specifying the covergence criteria (code as shown below), it seems that the library just does not return the right values (reprojection as shown below in the image).

Im wondering whether this could be the unit problem (but I've changed it to mm so the numbers are larger), or the number of pointclouds is just too small. I'm relatively new to this library, would be grateful if y'all can provide some advices .

```
icp.convergence_criteria_->setTranslationThreshold(0.01);
    icp.convergence_criteria_->setAbsoluteMSE(0.01);
```

this is the reproject 3D points image, blues are the desired result, while red it the calculated ones.
[image]

Comment: You can try setting `pcl::console::setVerbosityLevel(pcl::console::L_VERBOSE);` at the start of your program to get more log output. Or perhaps you are applying the transformation matrix incorrectly? Could be helpful if you post some more code

Comment: @IBitMyBytes thank you for your reply and suggestion. the below link shows my code.
[link](https://gist.github.com/pattylo/71e44b31c697b1cb094ded649122fff4)

as you can see, I create a vector with some 3D values, and then apply a transformation matrix on it to generate another list of point clouds (target). 
by solving the ICP problem, the algorithm should be returning a T matrix that approximate the aforementioned one, but it did not.<br/>

Am I doing sth wrong? If yes, please do provide me some suggestions, which will be great!

Comment: Might be that ICP gets stuck in a local optimum because of the low number of points. I don't know what you are trying to solve exactly, but maybe some other registration method like `SampleConsensusInitialAlignment` or `SampleConsensusPrerejective` is better suited for the job.

Comment: Ok understood. I'll defintely give it a try, and thanks again for your swift reply.